# How to add DATETIME value for session user

Tags: mysql, php, datetime

I am maintaining two tables:

- Employee table consists of username and password(for logging in)
- log table consists of login and logout time for the session user

With the click of a button, I should be able to capture/insert the time and session user to log table.

Here is my code for logging time and session user:

```
 <?php

session_start();
     if($_SESSION['username']) {
        $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    $tin= $_POST["timein"];
            $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

            mysql_select_db("attendance", $conn);

            $query = "INSERT INTO log (user, timein) VALUES ($user , NOW())";

            mysql_query($query, $conn);

            echo "<h2>you have logged your time!</h2>";

            mysql_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

Comment: @oNare the insert values aren't getting stored to table..

Comment: Add your `SHOW CREATE TABLE log;` statement to your question, and try running this on your `mysql` server: `INSERT INTO log (user, timein) VALUES (1 , NOW())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems with

```
$query = "INSERT INTO log (user, timein) VALUES ($user , NOW())";
```

Problem #1 : You need quotes around `$user`

Problem #2 : You need use `timein` instead of `NOW()`

Now, you need to make a decision.

If you want to supply the time yourself, then the query should be

```
$query = "INSERT INTO log (user, timein) VALUES ('$user','$tin')";
```

If you want the DB Server's clock time, then the query should be

```
$query = "INSERT INTO log (user, timein) VALUES ('$user',NOW())";
```

thus eliminating the need for `$tin= $_POST["timein"];`